# Change text in editpreference by code

Tags: android, preferences

Hi I have an edit preference and I want to change the value stored in it by code, is this possible?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
String input1 = hello;
prefs.getString("location", "").replace(prefs.getString("location", ""), input1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prefs.edit().putString("location", MODIFIED_STRING_HERE).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the put* method and then commit it to the shared preferences. Refer to [this example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

To update the text within your editText, use the setText method, refer to the [manpages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29)